# Visual Studio Code Analysis Warning - Multiple Dispose [CA2202]

Tags: c#

```
CA2202  Do not dispose objects multiple times   Object 'con' can be disposed more than once in method 'CreateHandheldDataViewModel.CreateSDF2(int, string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 647  DFStore.Modules.Store   CreateHandheldDataViewModel.cs  647
```

I get this error using `dispose`:

```
 private void CreateSDF2(int depoId, string fileName)
            {
                string cnnStr = String.Format("Data Source = {0}", fileName);

                var sqlEngine = new SqlCeEngine(cnnStr);
                sqlEngine.CreateDatabase();
                sqlEngine.Dispose();

                var con = new SqlCeConnection(cnnStr);
                var command = new SqlCeCommand { Connection = con };
                String[] createDbScripts = GetCreateDBScript2().Split(new[] { " go " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open();
                foreach (String s in createDbScripts)
                {
                    command.CommandText = s;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Close();

                con.Dispose();

                InsertDatatoDB2(depoId, fileName);
            }
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx, or any of [these similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ca2202)?

Comment: Yes I read this but NOT reseolve with this

Comment: Then please **mention the research you've done** - what have you learned, what have you tried, and what is still unclear or not working?

Comment: As @Matthew Watson stated you only need `Dispose()`. So you may even consider writing a `using-block.`

Comment: you should use a using/tryFinally block in any case. just consider con.Open() or the command will throw an exception --> your con.Dispose() ist skipped. This will thus result in CA error "dispose objects before loosing scope"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlConnection.Close()` is the functionally the same as `SqlConnection.Dispose()`.

Therefore these lines of code will dispose the connection twice if the state is not already closed:

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

You only need the `Dispose()`.

To clarify, the implementation of `SqlConnection.Dispose()` is:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this._userConnectionOptions = null;
        this._poolGroup = null;
        this.Close(); // <---------- It calls Close()
    }                 
    this.DisposeMe(disposing);
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

It seems that CodeAnalysis knows about this, and is issuing the warning.